# How do I get a string from an Access database?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I've been handed an Access database with 3 columns: Name, category, e-mail. What I'm trying to do is get out, as strings, all of the e-mails that match a given category.

I have a slight understanding SQL as I'm in the process of learning it. I've managed to churn out this bit of code, which populates a visual grid with the first names

```
Dim comm As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=.\AddressBook.mdb")
Dim addda As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT FirstName FROM Contacts", comm)
Dim dd As New DataTable("Name")
addda.Fill(dd)
DataGridView2.DataSource = dd
```

So I feel I'm getting fairly close, but I can't figure out how to get that list of first names to go into a string (or array of strings). All of the online tutorials and books I find seem to go over just displaying the data in a dataview.

Point in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim Names As New List(Of String)

Using comm As New OleDbConnection("Provider...")
  comm.Open()
  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT FirstName FROM Contacts", comm)
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
      While reader.Read
        Names.Add(reader("FirstName").ToString)
      End While
    End Using
  End Using
End Using
```

The Using format will automatically dispose of your data objects.

Comment: That OleDbReader, is that supposed to be OleDbDataReader?

Comment: Ah, that worked, thank you! This is my first time working with both VB.NET and databases. The whole process is a little daunting.

Comment: Also, you missed a End Using at the bottom there. Any reason you went with using and not Dim?

Comment: @cost Fixed it, again.  I use the "Using - End Using" format for all of my disposable objects.  Any object that implements the IDispose interface should be (in most cases) explicitly disposed of.  If you dim your connections and commands, you will have to "remember" to dispose of them later (ie comm.dispose).  If you don't, you're leaking memory.  End Using will dispose of the object for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure LarsTech's response will work, but going back to your original example, you can always loop through your DataTable (*dd*), looking at the DataRow collection.

```
Dim Names As New List(Of String)
For Each R As DataRow In dd.Rows.Count
    Names.Add(R.Item("FirstName").ToString)
Next
```

Then you can just check the count of *Names* and if it's greater than 0, iterate over that collection.