# Insert data From DatagridView to Access Database VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I cannot insert data from DataGridView to Access database. It shows Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement. Please help me. This is my code:

```
Try
    com = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    com.Connection = con
    Dim atdate As Date
    Dim id As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim time As String
    Dim status As String
    For x As Integer = 0 To ATCGRID.Rows.Count - 1
      atdate = ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
      id = ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
      Name = ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
      time = ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
      status = ATCGRID.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
      con.Open()
      str1 = "INSERT INTO EMP_ATTENDANCE(DATE,EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_TIME,EMP_STATUS)values(@DATE,@EMP_ID,@EMP_NAME,@EMP_TIME,@EMP_STATUS)"
      Dim com As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str1, con)
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", atdate)
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_ID", id)
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_NAME", Name)
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_TIME", time)
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_STATUS", status)
      com.ExecuteNonQuery()
      com.Dispose()
    Next 
    con.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Registered Successfully!", "Register", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
     MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Oledb Error")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Date" is most likely a keyword.  Try placing it in brackets: `[DATE]` in your SQL text.

Comment: @Thanzeem Glad it's working.  You should probably encapsulate all your data objects with `Using` statements, which will dispose the objects for you.  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348172/719186)

Comment: Also consider moving your command and parameter declaration outside of the loop and set the parameter values inside of the loop that way you aren't having to set-up the command memory for each row in the loop.